# Defining bullets for beamer

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

[image]

Hello, I want the following bullet structure for my presentation. Most importantly, I want to ensure that the bullet is vertically aligned with the text. I am using the Metropolis theme on Beamer. Could you kindly help? Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Please always include a short test document in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\circ$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{--}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The issue I’m facing with this code is that the first bullet in the main list is smaller than the subitem bullet. How can I get it to work?

Comment: @grumpyeconomist see my edited answer

Comment: It works! Thank you, kind sir!

Comment: You're welcome! (and please don't call me "sir" :) )